# Plot a function of two variables equal 0

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, gnuplot

I would like to plot the function *x*<sup>2</sup>(1 − *x*<sup>2</sup>) − *y*<sup>2</sup> = 0 in LaTeX.

I tried running following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      view={0}{90},
      no markers,
    ]

    \addplot3+[
      contour gnuplot={
        levels=0,
        labels=false,
      }
    ]
    {x^2(1-x^2)-y^2};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

but the output is 
[image]

But should be

[image]

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

@Superuser27 is correct about the missing *.  Additionally, I don't understand why you're using `\addplot3.`  Finally, that's not a function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-1:1,samples=1000]{ sqrt(x*x*(1-x*x)) * -1 };
    \addplot[domain=-1:1,samples=1000]{ (x*x*(1-x*x))^0.5 * 1 };
    \draw (axis cs:1,-0.07,1)--(axis cs:1,0.07);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I used addplot for the contour gnuplot. So i don‘t have to calculate the function equal 0  for y.

Answer (score 5):

[image: math]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ]
    \addplot[no marks,variable=\t,domain=0:360,samples=100] ({cos(\t)}, {0.5*sin(2*\t)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Best answer....

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble running your code (compatibility issues) but now it should work. I think the answer is simply that you missed a `*` in `{x^2(1-x^2)-y^2};`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      view={0}{90},
      no markers,
    ]
    \addplot3[
      contour gnuplot={
        levels=0,
        labels = false,
        },
      domain=-2:2,
      domain y=-1.3:1.3,
    ]
    {x^2*(1-x^2)-y^2};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how did you manage to compile it, I am having hard-time compiling it with the error being: `Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{texstudio_Ml6192_contourtmp0.table} could not be opened. {x^2*(1-x^2)-y^2};`. If you have some idea, let me know.

Comment: I got the same error. I had to look around online and found that Overleaf also complains but still gives you an output. @Raaja

Comment: Usually x^2 is implemented using exp(2*log(x)) which can't handle negative numbers.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Eventhough, as per your comment, I change it to `x*x*(1-x*x)-y*y`, I still encounter the same issue.

Comment: @Raaja I had the same problem first compiling it on my computer. So make sure you have installed gnuplot on your computer and then you need to add it to your path so that the program can find gnuplot. You also need to enable —shell-escape.